# Howto undo weird merge commit

Tags: git, merge, branch

I made a weird mistake (a merge commit done with SmartGit) and now origin/branch1 does point to that merge commit instead of the commit the remote repo branch1 indeed points to.
is there any way to move origin/branch1 back to where it points in the remote repo?

**No further answer required - I misunderstood the status of my local repository**
(don't know if this requires any action to close or delete this question as there is no answer if the question itself is wrong)

Comment: have you pushed yet?

Comment: no, I havent pushed yet

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

to move origin/branch1 back to the previous commit. (Use ~2,~3 and so on if you want to reset more commits, this is not fully clear in your question)

Then use rebase instead of merge to integrate the changes of the other branch - without merging:

```
git rebase other_branch_name
```

Comment: To run the 'reset' command I would need to checkout origin/branch1 (branch1 itself does not exist anymore). If I do so, git tells me that I am in 'detached HEAD' state)... Running the 'reset ...' anyway changes nothing.

Comment: What stops you from checking out `origin/branch1` as `branch1`?

Comment: okay, I did that but after the reset branch1 is where I want it to be but origin/branch1 ist still 1 commit ahead on that merge commit.

Comment: I might be wrong with my explanation - I need to check things one mor time... sorry if this was leading to confusion